# How to programatically generate random JavaFX xyCharts

Tags: java, random, javafx, series, scatter

So I want to generate random JavaFX XYcharts such as scatter charts.  I'm using netbeans 7.4.

I want to randomize the data going in and I want to randomize the number of series as well.  I already have the random data being added, but I do not know how to randomize the number of series that are used.  I plan to use a naming convention of series1, series2, ...,seriesN.  I'm just not sure how to go about it.

```
package basicscatter;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.ScatterChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.Random;

public class BasicScatter extends Application 
{

    @Override public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        stage.setTitle("Basic Scatter Chart");
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(0,50,5); //(start,end,step).
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0,1000,100);
        int count = 0;
        int NumEntries;
        int totalNumberOfSeries;
        int x; 
        int y;
        Random randomNumbers = new Random();

        final ScatterChart<Number,Number> sc = new ScatterChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
        xAxis.setLabel("X Axis");
        yAxis.setLabel("Y Axis"); 
        sc.setTitle("This is my Chart's Label");
        totalNumberOfSeries = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt(10);

 //would like to generate random Series here instead of hardcoding the series
        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();

        series1.setName("series 1");
        series2.setName("series 2");

        NumEntries = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt(100);

        while(count < NumEntries)
        {
            x = randomNumbers.nextInt(51);
            y = randomNumbers.nextInt(1001);
            series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(x,y));
            count++;
        }

        NumEntries = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt(100);
        count = 0;

        while(count < NumEntries)
        {
            x = randomNumbers.nextInt(51);
            y = randomNumbers.nextInt(1001);
            series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(x,y));
            count++;
        }


        sc.getData().addAll(series1, series2);
        Scene scene = new Scene(sc, 500, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(BasicScatter.class.getResource("Testcss.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do best to generate a random number of Series objects in a for loop like this:

```
List<XYChart.Series> seriesList = new ArrayList<Series>
int randomCount = randomNumbers.nextInt(100);
for(int i=0;i<randomCount;i++){
   XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
   series.setName("series " + randomCount);
   seriesList.add(series);
}
```

Then later you can iterate over all the series and add numbers to them (or you can do it within the for loop above).  You can easily iterate over every series with a for-each loop like this:

```
for(XYChart.Series series:seriesList){
    series.getData().add(...);
    ...
}
```

Comment: What package did you import to use ArrayList?  Also I think you you meant something like ArrayList<XYChart.Series> seriesList = new ArrayList<XYChart.Series>();  Though both what I'm suggesting and what you have for that line pop up with error messages for me...

Comment: So I got it to work for the code I added in previous comment it was just intellisense was being stupid.  Though I'm not sure what you mean by being able to add numbers to the series later.  I'm not 100% sure how to make sure the series are separated in a way where it's defined like series1, series2, ...seriesN.  I get naming them I just mean identifying them so that when I go to add the series to the chart I'm able to add the different series.

Comment: @user3003304 I'm not sure what you mean.  Do you understand the concept of a List, an Array, or an ArrayList?  It sounds like you want to give each of the variables a **name**, and that's not really necessary.  All you need is a pointer to that memory, and you can store any number of them (within reason) in an array list.

Comment: Didn't know I could do that with series and charts until now.